# Ansible. How to safely put ssh key to the remote rsync?

Tags: ansible, rsync

ansible 2.9.6

I want to transfer files between remote hosts. Move files from hosts `B`,`C` to `A`.
This code looks reasonable to me.

```
- hosts: host_B, host_C
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Transfer files
      synchronize:
        src: "{{ SHARED_DIR }}"
        dest: "{{ SHARED_DIR }}"
        mode: pull
      delegate_to: host_A
```

But as far as I understand, I need valid for `B` and `C` private SSH key on host `A` to do rsync. imho, it is not secure  put key to the host `A` as regular file.
Is it any way to keep it in memory or somehow during playbook execution only?

Comment: In theory using an `ssh-agent` should do that for you. Most modern desktop environments run an agent for you automatically. This may require some configuration to get ssh to forward the agent connection, but the ssh man pages should help out with that.

Comment: create a dedicated user with limited right on host A,B,C.

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: '{{ user.username }} | Create service user'
  user:
    name: '{{ user.username }}'
    password: '!'
    state: present
    create_home: false

- name: '{{ user.username }} | Set authorized_key'
  authorized_key:
    user: '{{ user.username }}'
    key: '{{ user.ssh_key }}'
    state: present
```

Create user, add authorized_key, make your's transfer, remove user.

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue by one string in `ansible.cfg`

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args =..... -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

I added `-o ForwardAgent=yes` to SSH section and all goes smoothly.